# Loss function space for a linear binary classification model

Tags: classification, loss-functions

How would the loss function look like for a *linear* binary classification model? Will it always be convex with a single extreme point?

I know that for *nonlinear* classification models there can be multiple local optimas, but can you assume that a linear classification model will only have 1 local optima (which is also the global optima) ? Or is this dependent of the loss function?

Comment: What is a linear classification model, logit/probit-style GLM? I can see that, but those models are nonlinear (in some sense), so the terminology could be confusing.

Comment: @Dave I see, what I mean with linear is that the model does not handle correlation between input features. So even if the output function is nonlinear (like sigmoid or any other logistic function) it will still not handle the correlation.

Comment: What is an example of a mode that does not handle correlation between features? Logistic regression can be pretty good, even when there is much correlation.

Comment: I think classifying XOR can't be done by a linear model. XOR is probably the easiest example where there is correlation between input features.

Comment: So that’s nonlinear by your definition…what would be linear by your definition? (Your definition is totally nonstandard, but you mean something by it, and you can edit the question and title to express what you mean once we pin down what exactly that is.)

Comment: Sorry, I might be referring to something separate. But I am sure that it is impossible to linearly separate the output values from XOR. Nonlinear activation-functions in a MLP must be used to learn nonlinear decision boundaries. So without any nonlinear activation functions, the MLP cannot classify XOR and must be a linear model, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on the loss function that is used. For example, in the case of logistic regression, where the loss function is the [binary cross entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_loss_function_and_logistic_regression), if the conditional probability distribution is modeled by any distribution from the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), then the binary cross entropy function will be convex in the parameters. More precisely, if the conditional probability distribution is modeled as
$$
q(c|\mathbf{x}) = \sigma(g(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{\theta}))
$$
where $c$ is the class, $\mathbf{x}$ is the input feature vector, $\sigma$ is the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), and $g$ is a chosen function parameterized by the parameters $\theta$, then the binary cross entropy function is convex in $\theta$ if $g$ is a linear function of $\theta$. Otherwise, if $g$ is a non-linear function of $\theta$, then the binary cross entropy function will be non-convex in $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks, but is not safe to assume this convex characteristic for any loss functions for a linear model? The motivation behind my question is from reading [an article](https://adversarial-ml-tutorial.org/adversarial_examples/) where it states "FGSM is exactly the optimal attack against a linear binary classification model" and I'm split on how the loss function must look like for this assumption to hold.

Comment: Surely, the loss function must have 1 extreme point for a projected gradient ascent step (FGSM) to be optimal against a linear model.

Comment: Loss functions are derived from some parameter estimation technique. In the case of the binary cross entropy function, the parameters that minimize it are the same parameters that maximize the likelihood function of the logistic model. Similarly, the parameters that minimize the mean squared-error also maximize the likelihood function of a gaussian model. In the case of these two loss functions, my answer still applies.